# When I render the color disappears

Tags: rendering, color

I am very new to Blender. When I render the image, the color that it used to have disappears.

This is the color it has in Solid mode:

[image: Solid mode]

And this is in Material Preview mode and when it is rendered:

[image: Material Preview mode]

I am using EEVEE engine.

Blender file: [image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Do you have materials defined in the *Material Properties* panel ?

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendered view needs materials. You don't have any materials.
You just have a color attribute, which you defined on the face corner as color:

[image]

if you create a material like that:

[image]

you will get your color.

Then select all objects and the object with the material at last, ctrl-l -> Material.

You need two materials or you rename your attribute - because sometimes you named it "Color" and sometimes "Attribute".

Comment: oh it solved! thank you so much!!

Comment: you are welcome